# Nuget package did not install on target machine

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, installation

I've created a windows service that uses Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects to install the service. The service was running fine until it needed the references from the Nuget package Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlManagementObjects

How do I add this package to the setup project so the references are available or can I simply install the nuget package on the target machine?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add this package to the setup project so the references are available or can I simply install the nuget package on the target machine?

Since nuget does not support the setup project, so we could not add that nuget package to the setup project directly.

To resolve this issue, the most direct method is manually add the `.dll` files in nuget package to the setup project (Right click the setup project->Add->Assemble...->Browse).

If manually adding the `.dll` file is not what you want, you can add a blank library project to the setup solution, then add the that nuget package to the library project.
Add the Project Output of the library project to the setup project (Add->Project Output...->Primary output):

[image]

In this case, all the `.dll` files in the nuget package are available for your setup project.

Hope this helps.